# Is there a way to stop the AVPlayer's rate property being reset?

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer

I'm using an AVPlayer object for video playback and have a control to adjust the player's rate.

This all works fine except that the rate value of the AVplayer object appears to be reset to 1.0 every time the stop/pause button is pressed. Is there a way to prevent this happening?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this up for the benefit of Google...

The rate property is reset to 1.0 each time the player begins to play, so you need to maintain the rate value elsewhere are re-apply it on each play.

Comment: This is the same behavior I get with MPMoviePlayer, and it happens even after seeking.  I filed a radar about it.

Answer (score 6):

`[AVPlayer play]`  is Equivalent to `[AVPlayer setRate:1.0]`

`[AVPlayer pause]` is Equivalent to `[AVPlayer setRate:0.0]`

Answer (score 0):

The MPMediaItem gives you a property to read the Beats Per Minute of the Media Item.

Something like this -

```
MPMediaItem *item = [[MPMediaItem alloc]init] ;
.
.
.
int BPM =  [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute];
```

Now calculate a rate at which you want to set the Media item's rate -

```
float rate = newBPM/(float)BPM; // lets say BPM = 100, You want to double the rate of the media then newBPM = 200
```

And now set this rate to the AVPlayer object-

```
[AVPLayer setRate:rate];
```

Answer (score 0):

The resetting of the rate by the 'play' method of AVPlayer is weird but true. I use to following code as a workaround to load a new player item, adjust play rate and let it play:

```
[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: movieURL]];
self.player.rate = PLAYER_RATE;
[self.player seekToTime: kCMTimeZero];
```